# Move back the pointer while reading from a video file

Tags: python, opencv, frame, python-imaging-library, video-processing

I am using opencv on Python. I am reading from a video file and analyzing each frame.
Once I read a frame, how do I move back the pointer so that when I execute the following line, I get the same frame.

```
frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
```

It would also help me, if I can get which frame it is actually pointed to and call a specific API to get only that particular frame back.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the question. Figured it out.
Anyways, it can be done as follows:

```
            frame_no=cv.GetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
            print frame_no
            cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,frame_no)
```

Thanks,